# Precision timing using DateTime possible?

Tags: .net

I would like to test the time required by certain methods and SQL queries in my code. I've tried doing the following:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

//Do something

DateTime end = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan ts = end - start;

int millis = ts.Milliseconds;
```

But I just don't feel that this is the right way of doing it. I often get back a value of 1 for some methods and values like 200 for others, are there any accurate ways to measure and record this kind of thing?

Comment: No. Use System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.

Comment: `DateTime` is based on 100 nanosecond ticks, so it shouldn't be a limitation for you. But `DateTime.Now` is only updated every few milliseconds, which causes the behavior you observed.

Comment: Thanks, so I know now not to use DateTime for anything requiring precision.

Answer (score 7):

Use [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class.

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
//your work
stopWatch.Stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Provides a set of methods and properties that you can use to accurately measure elapsed time using `Stopwatch` class. That is really good and can be used to measure and compare algorithm run time.

```
    using System.Diagnostics;
    // ...

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();

    // ...

    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed={0}",sw.Elapsed);
```